# Pointer and Struct member function

Tags: go

### Invoke function

When I define a struct `Lock` and a function `Test` with the struct `Lock` as the function receiver

```
type Lock struct {
}

func (self Lock) Test() {
    fmt.Println("Test Func")
}
```

I found that I can call this function with a `Lock` struct pointer

```
lock := &Lock{}
lock.Test()
```

The same, if I define a struct `Lock` and a function `Test` as the `Lock`'s pointer as the receiver, I can call this function through `Lock` struct instance.

So whatever the receiver is the struct itself or the struct pointer, I can call this function through the both? What's the reason. As my comprehension, the struct and the struct pointer are totally two different type!

### Interface

If a define a interface `Locker` like this

```
type Locker interface {
    Test()
}
```

And define a struct `Lock` and a function `Test` with the struct **instance** as the receiver, I can't assign a struct pointer variable to a `Locker` interface var.

On the contrary, If a define a struct `Lock` and a function `Test` with the struct **pointer** as the receiver, assign a struct instance variable to a `Locker` interface var can work!

I'm so confused about the language design. Can anybody give me some advice?

Comment: You're looking for the rules on [selectors](https://golang.org/ref/spec#Selectors)

Comment: And take a look at the language spec in general, especially the method set sections. And of course: Take the Tour of Go once more.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Usually, Go does things for you under the hood and this is typically one of those cases.

When you define a function with a struct as receiver and you pass it a pointer to the struct, then Go does the conversion for you: it passes a copy of the struct pointed to.

When you define a function with a pointer as a receiver and you pass it a struct, Go creates a pointer to this struct.

However, when defining an interface, you're working on types: The `Locker` interface defines a type which implements the function `Test()`.

And with interfaces, Go won't help you: if your type doesn't implement a method, then it does not implement the interface. No hidden conversion here.

Usually, it's better to be clear about what you want and how you want it and thus preventing Go from doing those weird conversions.

Comment: Not completely accurate.  Go still does a *bit* of conversion for interfaces.  The rule is that if you pass a pointer to a type into an interface, both pointer and value methods on that type can fulfill the interface.  If you pass the type itself in, only value methods on that type can fulfill the interface.  Example: https://play.golang.org/p/rUIeMBnXTY

Comment: Thanks for your answer! It really help me figure this out.