# Difference in a function implementation when instantiating an object with different function signatures

Tags: go

Came across the following differences a function implementations. What is the reasoning behind Example 1 returning a pointer and Example 2 returning an actual object?

```
type MyInterface interface {
    Func (param int) float64 //just random signature
}

//MyInterfaceImpl implements MyInterface
type MyInterfaceImpl struct {
}

//actual implementation 
func (myObj *MyInterfaceImpl) Func(param int) float64 {
    return float64(param)
}
```

Example 1: the pointer to the `MyInterfaceImpl` is returned when function returns an interface

```
func NewMyInterface() MyInterface {
    return &MyInterfaceImpl{}
}
```

Example 2: actual object of `MyInterfaceImpl` is returned when function returns the object

```
func NewMyInterfaceImpl() MyInterfaceImpl {
    return MyInterfaceImpl{}
}
```

**UPDATE:** This piece of code compiles and runs

```
func main() {
    myIf := NewMyInterface()
    fmt.Printf("Hi from inteface %f\n", myIf.Func(1000))

    myImpl := NewMyInterfaceImpl()
    fmt.Printf("Hi from impl %f\n", myImpl.Func(100))
}
```

**UPDATE2:** Question clarification.

This sounds weird (for me) to have a declaration of `func NewMyInterface() MyInterface` and a valid implementation of `return &MyInterfaceImpl{}` where a pointer is returned. I would expect to return an object of MyInterfaceImpl with `return MyInterfaceImpl{}`

If the language allows such types of constructs, there must be a reason for that. Eventually, I am looking for a following answer: "The function declaration returns an interface. Because the interface has a property X it is does not make sense to return an object, but the only valid option is a pointer".

Comment: Are you sure its not `NewMyInterface() *MyInterface {` for the first example?

Comment: @lbu Updated the description

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Golang Pointer and Struct member function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40112250/golang-pointer-and-struct-member-function)

Comment: Is the question about why `var myIf MyInterface = &MyInterfaceImpl{}` would be valid (as opposed to `var myIf *MyInterface = &MyInterfaceImpl{}`)?

Comment: I think this is different from the pointer/value thing (which I also wrote about: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23542989/pointers-vs-values-in-parameters-and-return-values/23551970). You return an interface if you don't necessarily want to expose everything about the type you're using internally, like because you might switch implementations. (For example, if you have something to return a cache or DB connection, you might wrap it in an interface that hides methods specific to the particular cache or DB driver being used.) You return the concrete type if you do want those details used.

Comment: Or is the question about why `myImpl.Func()` works, even though `Func` has a pointer receiver and `myImpl` is not a pointer?

Comment: `What is the reasoning behind Example 1 returning a pointer and Example 2 returning an actual object?` depends what they do, their members, how they are being used. With current examples its hard to tell. Now, as a rule of thumb, take interface, return structs. to read https://medium.com/@cep21/preemptive-interface-anti-pattern-in-go-54c18ac0668a

Comment: @mh-cbon *Example 1* **has to** return a pointer, as `MyInterfaceImpl` doesn't implement `MyInterface` (despite the name...) But I agree it's hard to tell what the question is.

Comment: indeed, i totally missed that part.

Comment: I am confused about what you are asking.  There are two functions that do different things.  Depending on context, they can both be useful.   Are you asking why NewMyInterface cannot return `MyInterfaceImpl{}`?

Comment: @ııı how do you tell that the ```MyInterfaceImpl``` does not implement ```MyInterface```? If it didn't, Example 1 cannot be compiled. @all I added the clarification

Comment: @Tim See ThunderCat's explanation below, they were faster. Also if you remove the `&`, the compiler's error will explain why

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Even though I'm not sure which part of the code the question is about, let me explain what the code does:

`MyInterface` is implemented by anything having a `Func(int)float64` method.
`*MyInterfaceImpl` has such a method. However, `MyInterfaceImpl` does not (the method has a pointer receiver).

`NewMyInterface()` thus has to return a pointer. `MyInterfaceImpl{}` wouldn't implement `MyInterface`.

Does this answer your question?

---

Another question might be why the call `myImpl.Func(100)` works, despite the above. This is because *Go* automatically takes the address of the receiver when calling its methods with pointer receivers.
This is explained in more detail for example [here](https://go101.org/article/unofficial-faq.html#method-set-relation).

Comment: Could you please clarify why ```MyInterfaceImpl``` does not implement ```MyInterface```? It sounds like I am missing a fundamental go knowledge here.

Comment: The [spec explains it](https://golang.org/ref/spec#Method_sets).  The method set for a value type does not include pointer receiver methods.